# vba reference workbook if active and last 7 characters of filename contain x?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks

```
Master Workbook 
Slave workbook
```

On a worksheet change event in my master workbook, if the user enters a number in cell C5 like so:

Master workbook

```
C5 = 1234
```

Then i want to look down column E on my slave workbook for this number.

Slave workbook

```
Column E    Column F
1222        Beans
1234        Cheese
```

If found, i want to grab the corresponding value from column F in the slave workbook and put this into cell C6 on my master workbook.

Master Workbook

```
C5 = 1234
C6: Cheese
```

The other issue is my slave workbook changes name from time to time, meaning i cannot reference it with a absolute reference. Instead i want to reference the slave workbook based on two conditions:

1. If the slave workbook is open
2. If the last 7 characters of the workbook file name are 'Volumes'

No matter what the slave workbook is renamed to, the last characters 'volumes' will remain in the file name like so:

```
file1 16.01.17 volumes.xls
or
file1 19.01.17 volumes.xls
```

EDIT
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target as Range) 
    Dim Dic As Object, key As Variant, oCell As Range, i&
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet

    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set w1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set w2 = Workbooks("workbookB.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    i = w1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For Each oCell In w1.Range("C5")
        If Not Dic.exists(oCell.Value) Then
            Dic.Add oCell.Value, oCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
        End If
    Next

    i = w2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For Each oCell In w2.Range("E4:E" & i)
        For Each key In Dic
            If oCell.Value = key Then
                oCell.Offset(, 1).Value = Dic(key)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I am brand new to vba so am not sure if my code is correct, but please can someone show me how to get it to do what i need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try edited code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Dic As Object, key As Variant, oCell As Range, i As Long
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet

    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set w1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    'With w1
    '   i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    'End With

    For Each oCell In w1.Range("C5")
        If Not Dic.exists(oCell.Value) Then
            Dic.Add oCell.Value, oCell.Offset(, -3).Value
        End If
    Next

    Dim wbInd   As Integer
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    For wbInd = 1 To Workbooks.Count ' <-- loop through all open workbooks
        If Workbooks(wbInd).Name Like "*volumes.xlsx" Then '<-- check if workbook name contains "volumes"
            Set wb2 = Workbooks(wbInd)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wbInd

    Set w2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With w2
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For Each oCell In w2.Range("A2:A" & i)
        For Each key In Dic
            If oCell.Value = key Then
                oCell.Offset(, 2).Value = Dic(key)
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

---

**Edit 1**: Moved the code to `Worksheet_Change` event, and run the code only if the value in cell "C5" is modified.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Dic As Object, key As Variant, oCell As Range, i As Long
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C5")) Is Nothing Then ' <-- run this code only if a value in cell C5 has change

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    If Not Dic.exists(Target.Value) Then
        Dic.Add Target.Value, Target.Offset(1, 0).Value
    End If

    Dim wbInd   As Integer
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    For wbInd = 1 To Workbooks.Count ' <-- loop through all open workbooks
        If Workbooks(wbInd).Name Like "*volumes.xlsx" Then '<-- check if workbook name contains "volumes"
            Set wb2 = Workbooks(wbInd)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wbInd

    Set w2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With w2
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For Each oCell In w2.Range("E2:E" & i)
        For Each key In Dic
            If oCell.Value = key Then
                Target.Offset(1, 0).Value = oCell.Offset(0, 1) '<-- put the the value in column F (offset 1 column) to cell C6 (one row offset)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```